# Positivity of the top Lyapunov exponent

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

I have a general question about the Oseledets Multiplicative Ergodic Theorem. In the context of the MET I'd like to know if there is some reasonably general sufficient condition which implies that the top Lyapunov exponent \lambda_1 is >0.

My specific situation involves a finite-state aperiodic irreducible Markov chain with values in SL(d,Z).
Thus a random trajectory of this Markov chain is a sequence of matrices
\omega=A_1,A_2,...A_n,...
where all A_i come from a finite subset S of SL(d,Z). I also know that the stationary distribution on S for this chain is the uniform distribution on S, and that S generates a "large" subgroup of SL(d,Z).

As I understand it, in this situation, the MET implies that 
for a.e. trajectory \omega=A_1,A_2,...A_n,...
of this Markov chain, for S_n=A_{n-1}...A_1
the operator norm of S_n grows as e^{\lambda_1 n} where \lambda_1 is the top Lyapunov exponent.

I'd like to be able to claim that in fact \lambda_1>0 in my case, so that ||S_n|| grows exponentially fast.

I hope that there is some general result implying positivity of \lambda_1 that could be applied here.

Thanks a lot,

Ilya Kapovich.

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive reference for this sort of thing seems to be Furstenberg, "[Noncommuting random products](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-108-03/S0002-9947-1963-0163345-0/S0002-9947-1963-0163345-0.pdf)", [*Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **108** (1963), 377-428](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163345).  I say this because I've seen it referenced in other places that consider similar questions; a quick glance through Furstenberg's paper suggests that some non-trivial study may be needed to answer your questions from his work.

A more direct treatment of your question can be found in Marcelo Viana's recent book "[Lectures on Lyapunov Exponents](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/lectures-lyapunov-exponents)" (Cambridge University Press).  I'm not sure if the entire book is available yet but at the moment the [first chapter](http://w3.impa.br/%7Eviana/out/lle.pdf) is available on [Viana's website](http://w3.impa.br/~viana/#[[Books%20%26%20Lecture%20Notes]]).  That chapter describes the case when $d=2$ and the matrices are chosen i.i.d., and quotes Furstenberg's paper as implying that the top Lyapunov exponent is positive as long as the monoid generated by $S$ satisfies a certain "pinching and twisting" condition; the proof, and the general case, seem to come later on in the book, in Chapters 6 and 7, which are not available online.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at Furstenberg's paper and will try to get a hold of Viana's book (it's supposed to be published this month but is not available yet). But I really hope that I don't have to undertake a non-trivial study, as you put it, to derive the needed result from Furstenberg. I am a geometric group theorist and my background in ergodic theory is fairly limited for the moment. So I really hope that there exists a reasonably direct reference....

Answer (score 1):

It should follow from a general theorem of Guivarc'h on simplicity of the Lyapunov spectrum for products of matrices with Markov dependence http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=772409

Comment: Thanks! I took a quick look at the paper of Guivarc'h. I will have to digest the conditions required for his theorem (I think they are satisfied in my case), but I don't understand how knowing that the Lyapunov exponents \lambda_1,...,\lambda_d are distinct would imply that \lambda_1>0. Could you clarify? Thanks, Ilya.

Comment: As long as your matrices all have determinant 1, then the Lyapunov exponents must sum to 0.  In particular, the only way to get $\lambda_1=0$ would be if all the Lyapunov exponents are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the canonical references (in the $SL(d, \mathbb{Z})$ case) is Goldsheid-Margulis and Goldsheid-Guivarc'h. For the positivity results to hold you need a moment condition (which is automatic when the support is finite, as it is in your case) and that the semi-group generated by the process is Zariski-dense (which is presumably what you mean by "large").

This is the canonical paper.

Goldsheid, I. Ya, and Yves Guivarc'h. "Zariski closure and the dimension of the Gaussian low of the product of random matrices. I." Probability theory and related fields 105.1 (1996): 109-142.

For groups other than $SL,$ there is a later paper by Guivarc'h alone. All these results are used in my preprint

Rivin, Igor. "Statistics of Random 3-Manifolds fibering over the circle." arXiv preprint arXiv:1401.5736 (2014).

which you might find interesting.

Comment: OK, very good, thanks! I sort of hacked out an ad hock argument showing that \lambda_1>0 for my particular situation, but it is certainly better to cite a general result. In my case the set S consists of all dxd matrices obtained from the identity matrix by changing a single off-diagonal entry from 0 to 1. I assume in this case the semigroup generated by S is Zariski-dense, right?